# Trigger a modal to show no a non click

Tags: javascript, html

I have a hidden modal that is want to trigger using `data-toggle`.
But it needs to start on it's own. so without a click.

I can show the modal using a icon with a `data-toggle` like this:

```
<a href="#RemoveSerialNumberModal" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-plus"></i></a>
```

This shows the modal 'AddSerialNumberModal'.

Now do I wanna check if `!empty($_GET['sn'])` and if it isn't I wanna open the modal on it's own.

I tried it with JS like this:

```
$('#RemoveSerialNumberModal').modal();
$('#RemoveSerialNumberModal').modal(show);
$('#RemoveSerialNumberModal').data-toggle(modal);
```

But that doesn't work.

(I really wanna do it in JS).

**-------------edit-------------**

```
<script>alert('where here stage 1 tho!');
        $("#RemoveSerialNumberModal").dialog({modal: true});
        alert('where here stage 2 tho!');</script>
```

This is how I test this. When I run the example it alerts the first 1 but doesn't show the second alert. So it breaks somehow on the code in the middle.

Comment: use `$('#RemoveSerialNumberModal').modal('show');`

Comment: I just tried your example, but it didn't work. New idea?

Comment: try  $("#RemoveSerialNumberModal").dialog({modal: true});

Comment: thnx. But your example doens't work @Viraj.

Comment: Do you have another idea?

Answer (score 0):

you can trigger click function if other way are not working to show modal

```
<a id="someid" href="#AddSerialNumberModal" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-plus"></i></a>

$('#someid').trigger('click');
```

Comment: thnx for you help. But your example doens't work for me.

Comment: by click on <a id="someid" href="#AddSerialNumberModal" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-plus"></i></a> modal popup or not ?

Comment: Look at my added info in my question. I get my first alert but after that not the modal or the second alert